# Overloading RESTful server with Keras (Theano) model through JMeter

Tags: flask, keras, jmeter, scale, theano

I have a keras (Theano) model for predicting sentiment out of a utterance. Moreover, I created a RESTful server with Flask for wrapping the model into it.
My goal is comparing the performance with a not-scaled and scaled system. Firstly, I wanted to try with the not-scaled one. In order to overload the requests, I use Apache Jmeter, which simulates 100 users over time by means of threads.

The code is available at [this](https://github.com/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm) github page.

Unfortunately, running the tests, the above mentioned model crashes with this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2314, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1760, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 458, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 573, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/sentiment-lstm/predict.py", line 54, in post
    "value": self.predict([question])[0][0]
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/sentiment-lstm/predict.py", line 66, in predict
    pred = self.__model.predict(x=X_test_pad)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1169, in predict
    steps=steps)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 294, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1388, in __call__
    return self.function(*inputs)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 917, in __call__
    storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 325, in raise_with_op
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 903, in __call__
    self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 963, in rval
    r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)
  File "/home/lcarnevale/Dropbox/git/lcarnevale/sentiment-lstm/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/scan_module/scan_op.py", line 952, in p
    self, node)
  File "scan_perform.pyx", line 546, in theano.scan_module.scan_perform.perform

TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
Apply node that caused the error: forall_inplace,cpu,scan_fn}(Shape_i{1}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, DeepCopyOp.0, Shape_i{1}.0, Subtensor{::, int64:int64:}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}.0, Subtensor{::, int64:int64:}.0, Subtensor{::, :int64:}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}.0, Subtensor{::, :int64:}.0, Subtensor{::, int64:int64:}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}.0, Subtensor{::, int64:int64:}.0, Subtensor{::, int64::}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}.0, Subtensor{::, int64::}.0)
Toposort index: 44
Inputs types: [TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(float32, 3D), TensorType(float32, (True, False, False)), TensorType(float32, (True, False, False)), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, row), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, row), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, row), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, row), TensorType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: ['No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes', 'No shapes']
Inputs strides: ['No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides', 'No strides']
Inputs values: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
Outputs clients: [[], [], [InplaceDimShuffle{1,0,2}(forall_inplace,cpu,scan_fn}.2)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

I am not really sure what is the error here. Could it be an ghost out of memory issue? Or what?

Lorenzo.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like an OOM issue to me

> 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Most probably there is a [None](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) constant which you're using not properly so it is not connected with high loads so I would recommend double checking your code and start with functional/[unit tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)

If you want to track memory leaks on Python and OS level consider using the following:

- [Python Profilers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) for collecting runtime information
- An [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) tool or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) for collecting essential OS health metrics like CPU, RAM, Swap, Disk and Network usage